# Android Styling List

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have just finished my application and now I am trying to style it. Throughout the application I used a combination of fragments and activities.

I have been using a lot of list either using the default ListFragment style or just a simpleCursorAdapter list style. My problem is trying to make the lists the same.

I am trying to style the two the same way as the default ListFragment, which has well spaced rows with easy to read writing.

Does anyone know what style this is? Or an easy styling method to make the all the lists the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps :)

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,   MobileMuni.getBookmarkStore().getRecentLocations()) {
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    String currentLocation = RouteFinderBookmarksActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.Current_Location);
    int textColor = textView.getText().toString().equals(currentLocation) ? R.color.holo_blue : R.color.text_color_btn_holo_dark;
    textView.setTextColor(RouteFinderBookmarksActivity.this.getResources().getColor(textColor));

    return textView;
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didnt take your method, instead I created a new XML layout with the same attributes as the simple list  view and then just applied that to the list. Thanks for the help though +1 all round, feel free to do the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you make a common xml file for the layout of the list view and then use it in adapter instead of making use of system default one's.

Comment: I was going to try that if there was no default theme I could use to make the listview look better

Comment: haven't you tried android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 one

Comment: I did try that but it turned all the text white in the list

Comment: then a better fix will be to set the color in adapter of the view

Comment: And if none of the data is being displayed in the list using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, so the list is there but all the rows are blank?

Comment: if there wont be any data then the list would just be empty just set up the textView color in adapter

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I created a new XML layout containing the same attributes as android simple list view and then applied that to all the lists to make them the same.

**Listview.XML**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/recipeName"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```